# Openstack - Connectivity between instances on 2 separate nodes

Tags: networking, vlan, bridge, openstack

I have the following setup:
 1 x Management Node (node A)
 2 x Compute Nodes (node B & C)
 1 x Volume Node (node D)

Relevant configurations:
VlanManager
multi_host=true

Node  B[eth0=192.168.6.102;br100=10.1.0.6]
Node  C [eth0=192.168.6.103;br100=10.1.0.4]

I can ping between instances on the same node,but not with instances in different nodes.
If I run "brctl br100 eth0" , Instances can ping between nodes, but I loose conectivity on eth0 (192.168.6.102/192.168.6.103)

What do I have to change to be able to ping instances between nodes while maintaining normal connectivity on eth0 ?

Comment: 1. How many physical interfaces on each node? How exactly do they connect, or are the bridged interfaces purely logical interfaces and operate totally within the VM/cloud environment? 2. Do you have a complete config, as in code, (relevant, scrubbed of security blablabla's) for the two nodes?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to run your nodes with a single physical network interface. What you see is normal, because when you enslave the `eth0` physical interface to the `br100` bridge, you have to assign IP addresses to the bridge itself, and not to the physical interface.

There is a [good example](http://docs.openstack.org/essex/openstack-compute/admin/content/configuring-openstack-compute-basics.html) in the OpenStack manual, but it does not cover the case of having your node handle two different IP networks on the same physical interface. You can do that by adding an address to `br100`. Summing up the relevant parts:

1. In `/etc/nova/nova.conf` on Node B, you will have something like:

   ```
   my_ip=10.1.0.6
   public_interface=br100
   vlan_interface=eth0
   flat_network_bridge=br100
   flat_interface=eth0
   ```
2. In `/etc/network/interfaces` on Node B, you will have something like:

   ```
   auto br100
   iface br100 inet static
       bridge_ports eth0
       bridge_stp off
       bridge_maxwait 0
       bridge_fd 0
       address 192.168.6.102
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       network 192.168.6.0
       broadcast 192.168.6.255
       gateway 192.168.6.xxx

   auto br100:1
   iface br100:1 inet static
       address 10.1.0.6
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       broadcast 10.1.0.255
   ```

I believe that this should work correctly.

Comment: There are actually two interfaces on each node.
One is the public interface (eth1) and the other the "internal" one (eth0)
Here is the current config of one of the compute nodes:

    multi_host=true
    network_manager=nova.network.manager.VlanManager
    network_host=XPTO
    vlan_interface=eth0
    my-ip=192.168.6.102
    enabled_apis=metadata
    public_interface=eth1
    flat_interface=eth0

    dmz_cidr=169.254.169.254/32
    ec2_dmz_host=169.254.169.254
    metadata_host=169.254.169.254